# Unable to add node to XML book file using xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces, xmlstarlet

I am trying to add another "revision" node to my XML file using xmlstarlet but have not been successful. Here's my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" xmlns:mw="http://abcxyz.com/namespace/secbook" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="5.0-variant secbook5.0" status="some_phase">
  <title><xi:include href="urn:abcxyz:pn:tm_test.xml"><xi:fallback><!-- fallback for tm_test --></xi:fallback></xi:include>Interface Reference</title>
  <info>
    <productname>
      <xi:include href="urn:abcxyz:pn:tm_test.xml">
        <xi:fallback>
          <!-- fallback for tm_test -->
        </xi:fallback>
      </xi:include>
    </productname>
    <releaseinfo>
      <xi:include href="urn:abcxyz:pn:this_release_name.xml">
        <xi:fallback>
          <!-- fallback for this_release_name -->
        </xi:fallback>
      </xi:include>
    </releaseinfo>
    <revhistory>
      <revision>
        <revnumber>Online</revnumber>
        <date>July 2021</date>
        <revremark>Version 2.3</revremark>
      </revision>
      <revision>
        <revnumber>Online</revnumber>
        <date>Jan 2022</date>
        <revremark>Version 2.4</revremark>
      </revision>
    </revhistory>
    <biblioid class="pubsnumber">interface_ref</biblioid>
    <subjectset>
      <subject>
        <subjectterm>SOMETERM</subjectterm>
      </subject>
    </subjectset>
  </info>
  </book>
```

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
xmlstarlet edit -s /book/info/revhistory --type elem --name revisionTMP --value "" \
            -s /book/info/revhistory/revisionTMP --type elem --name revnumber  --value "Online" \
            -s /book/info/revhistory/revisionTMP --type elem --name date  --value "Jul 2022" \
            -s /book/info/revhistory/revisionTMP --type elem --name revremark  --value "Version 2.5" \
            -r /book/info/revhistory/revisionTMP -v revision \
           ./test_book.xml
```

While this code works on a simpler XML file like this one where I have been able to successfully add a new "student", it fails on the larger "test_book.xml" file. What am I missing? I am open to other elegant solutions not involving `xmlstartlet`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Students>
  <student>
    <name>john</name>
    <id>123</id>
  </student>
  <student>
    <name>mike</name>
    <id>234</id>
  </student>
</Students>
```

I put the xmlstarlet command in s shell script. The script executes but nothing changes.

Comment: *What am I missing?* Your file uses namespaces.

Comment: So how do I get this to work with namespaces?

Comment: @Cyrus based on your suggestion, I did this:
```xmlstarlet edit -s "//_:revhistory" --type elem --name revisionTMP --value ""\
-s "//_:revhistory/revisionTMP" --type elem --name revnumber  --value "Online" \```

etc. This works. Is my solution robust?

Comment: XSLT transformation would be the best way to transform one XML into another.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the option `-L` to actually edit the file?

From `xmlstarlet ed --help`:

`-L (or --inplace)   - edit file inplace`